# Do Ruby on Rails 3 Jquery AJAX POST requests need the authenticity_token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, security

According to the Rails security guide, if you use protect_from_forgery, all non-GET requests include an authenticity token.  When I have Jquery AJAX POST requests, however, I don't see the authenticity_token param as one of the params in the request.  Is this how it's supposed to work?

Also, it seems that POST requests from outside a session (curl in a script) don't require an authencity_token, either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails will send this parameter in the headers rather than in the post data. You need to include the built in rails UJS library to get this to work. Take a look at the headers in your request and you should see one called X-CSRF-Token.